# How can I accessing a 3rd party plugin (phonegap-facebook-plugin) in Intel XDK?

Tags: facebook, cordova, intel-xdk

I am importing the Wizcorp phonegap-facebook-plugin using the intelxdk.config.additions.xml file with this code:

```
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" intelxdk:value="https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/">
    <intelxdk:param intelxdk:name="APP_ID" intelxdk:value="MyActualAppID" />
    <intelxdk:param intelxdk:name="APP_NAME" intelxdk:value="fizz points" />
</intelxdk:plugin>
```

I've read and understand that I will not be able to test this 3rd party plugin in the emulator, or via the test or debug tabs, so I've created a test build for Android.

Based on the documentation, I believe I am supposed to reference this API via calls to the facebookConnectPlugin, such as:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["publish_stream", "publish_actions", "offline_access"],
     fbLoginSuccess,
     function (error) { alert("There was an error: " + error) });
```

However, I know that in the built app, as in the emulator, the facebookConnectPlugin is not defined, because I get an alert based on the following block:

```
if (typeof facebookConnectPlugin != 'undefined'){

    // do stuff

} else {

    alert("FacebookConnectPlugin Not Defined");

}
```

I assume this is because I need to include the 3rd party library in my code in addition to including it in my project where suggested by the helpful comments, something like:

```
<!-- Most third-party libraries should go here. References (below) are just examples to give you the general idea... -->
<!-- <script src="lib/mc/hammer.js"></script> -->
```

Initially, I didn't know the path where the 3rd party library is ultimately located in the package after the build tool retrieves it.  But I was told that I could change the .apk extension to .zip extract and explore the contents.

I did this, and found that the library was stored in:

> www/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/www/phonegap/plugin/facebookConnectPlugin/facebookConnectPlugin.js

So I added the following to my index.html file:

```
<script src="plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/www/phonegap/plugin/facebookConnectPlugin/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
```

However, when built, my test to see if the FacebookConnectPlugin is defined still fails.

Thanks!

Noah

[I've essentially asked the same question on the Intel forums here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/536743 . No solution yet, but if I get one I will post it here.]

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your app and install it on your device to test the WizCorp Facebook plugin.  Please make sure you follow the instructions for configuring your app on Facebook.

*note* the Emulator (simulator) does not support third party plugins as you have noted.  Same for using App Preview to test.  You must build your app in the cloud.

thanks,
Ian

Comment: Appreciate the attempt, but I am testing it on the device after build.

Comment: Hi Noah,  Not sure why you downvoted it...doesn't encourage poeple to respond back.  I'm using the plugin right now.  If you look on the WizCorp commits, you can see I pushed an update in there for android-support-v4.jar

Comment: Again, I appreciate the attempt, but you disregarded information in my question, and didn't answer the question.  I had already stated that I am testing on the device, and have received messages during the build process indicating that the library has been properly imported. My challenge is that I can't reference the library in code.  If you edit your answer to address my question based on the information it contains, I will happily upvote it :)

Comment: I don't care about SO points.  I was confused because you kept mentioning "emulator" and passed over it.  Did you do the test in the debug tab to see if there is an error?  I'm able to use the demo they've provided fine without having to add anything additional.  I will try to get a bundle up somewhere that you can download that does work.  Keep an eye on this.  Without seeing your code though, it's tough to debug.  You can email html5tools@intel.com with a password protected zip bundle and we'll test it out (if it's not password protected our spam filters will remove js files)

Comment: Ok - try this project out. I was able to build and get the FB dialog to show (it will say invalid app id: Foobar) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wrsXcoFaJCNm1RNjBsRm1lTU0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the `facebookConnectPlugin` object from inside device ready event?

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function() {
    // try in here
}, false);
```

It could be `undefined` if you are accessing it from outside as the plugin is not ready to be used yet.